# Getting ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 in Github Actions

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js, github-actions

I am trying to connect to Postgres using docker in github actions. Here is my github actions file:

```
    name: Carbon Link backend server CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ 'develop', 'PC-3-setup-github-actions-on-pr-request' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ 'develop', 'PC-3-setup-github-actions-on-pr-request' ]
jobs:
  # label of the container job 
  postgres-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        # `POSTGRES_HOST` is `postgres`
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: carbonlink
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          # optional (defaults to `5432`)
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
          # optional (defaults to `postgres`)
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        # set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    env: 
      NODE_ENV: test
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/carbonlink
    steps:
      # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Disable husky preparation
        run: npm set-script prepare ''
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Migrate
        run: npm run db:migrate
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test
```

Everything works up to this command

```
Run npm run db:migrate
```

In which I get this response:

> express-sequel-passport@1.0.0 db:migrate
> ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 17.9.0, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.3.5]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "test".

**ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432**

This is my config.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    "password": process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    "host": process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.POSTGRES_DIALECT
  },
  "test": {
    "url": "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/carbonlink",
    "dialect": 'postgres'
  },
  "production": {
    "username": process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    "password": process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    "host": process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.POSTGRES_DIALECT
  }
}
```

Here is the docker-compose file for reference:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: pgDocker
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USERNAME
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_TEST_DB
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./create_test_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_test_db.sh
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadminDocker
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - 5555:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./setup/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

The way I would connect locally is to execute docker-compose up that will spin up the container with postgres.

I dont understand why I am not connecting to postgres still. Is there another step I should do? Thanks!

Comment: Just an observation: you used `POSTGRES_USERNAME` as environment name instead of `POSTGRES_USER` in your docker-compose file.

Comment: it shouldnt be the problem because it works locally when i execute `docker-compose up`

Comment: hmmm - using services in yaml should start the container and setup the shared networking so it's available to the host.  Maybe try and list the running containers in a step right before the migrate step??  Is it possible is shut down sometime between starting and the migrate because of he health check intervals?? just guessing

Comment: I ran it locally using `act` command and the tests ran, maybe its because I am running on localhost so it works locally but not in github servers?

Answer (score 2):

Can you also try the connection string from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`? I succeeded using your yml configuration on github actions. The only difference is the `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score -3):

Had same problem,

Found the solution, I forgot to add ports into the service description

Comment: What is the port are we supposed to specify?

Comment: In the example above, it specifies
`ports:
      - 5432:5432`
So 5432, if you juste copy past its sample

Comment: I had this previously set to `5432`, still produced an error.

Comment: can't help without more details

Comment: your solution is incomplete, that's all. there are other reasons behind the ports issue

Comment: i don't know for @richard zhang who is the first author. Personaly, my solution is complete, was only the ports. Cause no news of original author, you can't say it's not the solution. Moreover, if you know more reasons, please expose.